# Access Azure App Service ConnectionString from ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I've got an azure app service that I've set up like this:

[image: Azure Service Settings]

But when I call `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("db")` I get `null` back.

I've read articles like this https://mderriey.com/2018/08/21/azure-app-service-connection-strings-and-asp-net-core/ which say "it just works", but they're all several years old. I assume something's changed, but what?

Enumerating over all settings in my `IConfiguration` object I've got no connection strings. I do in development, where my `appsettings.development.json` has a `connectionStrings: { db: "" }` defined.

I can see and read the ENV variable: `POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_db` from within code, and it's value is correct (what I've set via the Azure portal).

Should I expect to be able to do `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("db")`? Or am I expected to switch between reading env variables in prod vs dev.

Do I need to include some nuget package to make `IConfiguration` work under Azure with these ENV variables and their mad prefixes?

My `startup.cs` basically looks like:

```
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Nothing else in there of interest to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_` prefix isn't supported by the environment variables configuration provider. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#connection-string-prefixes) shows this, in an indirect fashion, where it states that the following prefixes *are* supported:

> - `CUSTOMCONNSTR_`
> - `MYSQLCONNSTR_`
> - `SQLAZURECONNSTR_`
> - `SQLCONNSTR_`

It's also apparent in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/src/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L17-L20) for the provider.

There are a couple of options for working around this:

1. Change the *Type* to `Custom` in the *Connection strings* section of the Azure portal.
2. Change to an *Application setting* of `ConectionStrings:db` in the Azure portal.

---

This is being tracked on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36123.

Answer (score 4):

I got confused as well, so here it is:

You have two options to specify Connection String locally:

1. launchSettings.json (environmentVariables section)

```
  "environmentVariables": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
     "SQLAZURECONNSTR_SomeConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=blah"
   }
```

2. appSettings.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=blah"
  }
```

Having either way will allow you to get the connection string setting by calling:

```
IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("SomeConnectionString")
```

Function call above will also work when deployed to Azure, as it is using `EnvironmentVariables` configuration provider to read settings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the config from the interface

```
IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("db")
```

try to get it from

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("db")
```

And in production you have an empty string in production.appsetting.json and add the value in azure(appservice) configuration directly under connectionstrings(this will override the json setting file). And no nugets are needed for reading from appsettings

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was simply showing the type of IConfiguration for the purpose of asking a question, otherwise it wouldn't compile. As for your 2nd tip, thats what I've done, that's what the question asks.

Comment: sorry, are you saying you need a placeholder connection string key in the production json in order for it to be overridden? Or will (should) it get set regardless. I have no connectionstring keys in my prod json

Comment: yes there need to be an placeholder. The value can be what ever it will be replaced ie "SetInAzure"