# .NET 6.0 app on Azure App Service (Linux) can't find connection string

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

Azure first-timer here trying to deploy a .NET 6.0 app to App Service (Linux OS).

In my app, I have a line as follows:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
```

This exception gets thrown on app startup, despite the fact that I'm setting the "DefaultConnection" connection string in the app config in Azure as follows:

[image: conn string]

What am I missing?

Comment: Connection name has to be prefixed with connection type. Ex:SQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection. Please refer [Configuring connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @HarshithaV all the docs say is that "At runtime, connection strings are available as environment variables, prefixed with the following connection types". So I did end up getting it working with a hack, doing `connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection")` BUT this isn't a great solution, because I can't figure out how to _also_ simply do `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I'm using Postres, and right now there is a bug/deficiency that prevents .NET from exposing Postgres connection strings to the app.

I didn't think it was even relevant that is a was a Posgres connection string, but here we are.

The fix ended up being to mark the connection string as a "Custom" type in Azure App Service configuration. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62198728/363789

Here is a related Github issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/95890